# Advice: Different Content Country Sites

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce

Whats the best practice to create a website in EE, that is different country (Not language) and change the content based on this.

I'm considering using MSM, due to the client needing different categories & pages per site, but then plugins such as CartThrob don't support the ability to span products across multiple sites via MSM.

Answer (score 1):

I actually have used MSM in this case, and to good results. We shared common code in one 'site' and embedded into other sites as needed. Each MSM site stored the things that were different/unique to that country.

I'd be curious to hear what Matt ran into.

But the eCommerce piece might be a deal-killer.

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend not using MSM for this; I think it will cause you more problems than it solves.

Have you considered having different category groups for each country and then on listing pages, limiting by category_id in the weblog:entries tag?